# Can anyone explain this curious batch behavior using "%~t1" and give a solution

Tags: date, time, parameters, batch-file

can anyone explain the following to me:

The Code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL disabledelayedexpansion

set pf=C:
set url=http://www.rarlab.com/rar
set fn=config.sys

call :SUB1 "%url%" "%fn%"
goto :EOF

:SUB1
echo:PATH=[ %pf%\%~2 ]
if exist %pf%\%~2 (call :READDATE "%pf%\%~2") & set "_datum1=%_result%"
echo:Date1=[ %_datum1% ]
if exist %pf%\%~2 (call :READDATE "%pf%\%~2") & set "_datum2=%_result%"
echo:Date2=[ %_datum2% ]
goto :EOF

:READDATE
SETLOCAL
for %%A in (%~1) do set "_tvar=%%~tA"
echo:Date=[ %_tvar% ]
ENDLOCAL & set "_result=%_tvar%"
exit /b 0 

:end
```

The Output:

```
PATH=[ C:\config.sys ]
Date=[ 10.06.2009 23:42 ]
Date1=[  ]
Date=[ 10.06.2009 23:42 ]
Date2=[ 10.06.2009 23:42 ]
```

So if you look at line 3 of the output there is no Date/Time - Why ?????
If it's not a big bug of CMD.EXE can anyone please help me solving the problem. I need both
Date/Time data for a comparison.

ADDENDUM:

Is it somehow possible to do read the date/time in the first "sub" without using the second "READDATE" ??

i tried the following:

```
if exist %pf%\%~2 set "_datum1=%pf%\%~t2"
```

but that does not work because the "~t2" seems only to work with a variable that holds the full
path and filename together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL disabledelayedexpansion

set pf=C:
set url=http://www.rarlab.com/rar
set fn=config.sys

call :SUB1 "%url%" "%fn%"
goto :EOF

:SUB1
echo:PATH=[ %pf%\%~2 ]
if exist %pf%\%~2 (call :READDATE "%pf%\%~2")
set "_datum1=%_result%"
echo:Date1=[ %_datum1% ]
if exist %pf%\%~2 (call :READDATE "%pf%\%~2")
set "_datum2=%_result%"
echo:Date2=[ %_datum2% ]
goto :EOF

:READDATE
SETLOCAL
for %%A in (%~1) do set "_tvar=%%~tA"
echo:Date=[ %_tvar% ]
ENDLOCAL & set "_result=%_tvar%"
exit /b 0 

:end
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem happens because `%_result%` is evaluated first and its value is put in before the command `if exist %pf%\%~2 (call :READDATE "%pf%\%~2") & set "_datum1=%_result%"` is run. So for the first one you get no result and for the second one you get the first one's result.

Is there a reason why you disabled delayed expansion? One way to solve this problem would be to enable delayed expansion (by replacing `SETLOCAL disabledelayedexpansion` with `SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion`) and change `%_result%` to `!_result!`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Looking on the answer of @foxidrive the solution was so simple but i wasn't be able to grasp it.